# What is the payoff function for games with more than two players?

Tags: notation, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

For two player games, with payoff matrices $(A,B)$, let $x \in \Delta_x$ denote the mixed strategy of player $1$, and $y \in \Delta_y$ denote the mixed strategy of player $2$.

Then the payoff function for player $1$ is written as,

$\mathcal{U}^1(x,y) = x^TAy$

and for player $2$ is

$\mathcal{U}^2(x,y) = y^TBx$

See definition 4:  http://euler.fd.cvut.cz/predmety/game_theory/games_bim.pdf

What would the payoff matrix look like for games with more than two players? Can someone provide a simple example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In definition 4, the expected payoff for Player $i$ could instead be written as
$$
U_i(\boldsymbol{p},\boldsymbol{q})=\sum_{(s,t)\in S\times T}u_i(s,t)p_sq_t.
$$
This say the utility of a pair of mixed strategies $(\boldsymbol{p},\boldsymbol{q})$ for Player $i$ is
the SUM of the utility of a pair of pure strategies $(s,t)$ for Player $i$ MULTIPLIED BY the probability $s$ is chosen MULTIPLIED BY the probability $t$ is chosen
ranging over all pairs of strategies $(s,t)$ in $S\times T$.

For three players, where for the third player their set of strategies is $U$, the definition is then
$$
U_i(\boldsymbol{p},\boldsymbol{q},\boldsymbol{r})=\sum_{(s,t,u)\in S\times T\times U}u_i(s,t,u)p_sq_tr_u.
$$
Here's an example (ignore the part on finding equilibria): [image: three_player_game]